# OpenGL ES GLKBaseEffect vs changing vertices position

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to OpenGL and I can't find info about which way to choose if I want to move object.

I've created a simple triangle using only vertices array (no shaders) and display it on the screen. Next I want to move my triangle (to the right/left sides). As I see it there is two ways:

1. use GLKBaseEffect and play with GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation and GLKBaseEffect.transform.projectionMatrix property
2. change coordinates in vertices array

which way is more correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Translation.  You never want to change coordinates in array.

Comment: While "never" is perhaps too restricting, it's a good rule of thumb that if you can transform your model using just the matrices then matrices are the way to go

Comment: @BartoszCiechanowski i'm just trying to make shure that he will remember it :)

Comment: ok ) so true way is to work with matrices. but what if I want to make two object come closer or far away from each other? it is more logical to change coordinates of two object, but now I'm doubts.

Comment: @Nils you do translation draw one object then do translation again and draw another. Read this http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm